# Bootstrap 4: Vertical align image in a circle button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a circle button that needs to have a plus image in the center of it. The thing is, I can't seem to vertical align that image without resorting to messing with margins.

Is there an easier, Bootstrap-y way of doing this?

Here's my code:

```css
.btn-circle {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* the button is supposed to be a circle, but for some reason it's not showing up like that in this snippet */
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<a class="btn btn-circle mr-3" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dt9b7pad3/image/upload/v1499509391/58a2031e6af142ce619ba2a2_plus-symbol_y6vqca.svg" height="20"></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to make the `<a..></a>` display:flex using the included `d-flex` class.

```
<a class="btn btn-circle mr-3 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dt9b7pad3/image/upload/v1499509391/58a2031e6af142ce619ba2a2_plus-symbol_y6vqca.svg" class="" height="20"></a>
```

The use the appropriate util classes to center:
`justify-content-center align-items-center`

https://www.codeply.com/go/BE0Jh6NqrL

Comment: This is it! Thanks, Zim!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to achieve? I vertically centered the `<a>` containing the `<img>` with

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%)
```

Bootstrap's `border-radius` seemed to override yours, so I added `!important` to it.

```css
.btn-circle {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 50% !important;
}
.btn-circle a{
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.btn-circle img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* the button is supposed to be a circle, but for some reason it's not showing up like that in this snippet */
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<a class="btn btn-circle mr-3" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dt9b7pad3/image/upload/v1499509391/58a2031e6af142ce619ba2a2_plus-symbol_y6vqca.svg"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.btn-circle {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    
   
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <a class="btn btn-circle mr-3 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
        <img style="height: 30px;padding-left:15px;" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dt9b7pad3/image/upload/v1499509391/58a2031e6af142ce619ba2a2_plus-symbol_y6vqca.svg" class="" height="20">
    </a>
</div>
```